# React.js: Use overlay spinner on index.js when calling API

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to put a spinner on my app whenever there is an ongoing API call

I had success in tracking the API call by using a library called `react-promise-tracker`

Usage below:

ProfileMaintenancePage.js

```
import { trackPromise } from 'react-promise-tracker';

  const saveProfile2 = () => {
    let lastModifier = "test"
    let status = "NEW"
    let createdBy = "test"
    const mapSelectedModules = selectedModules.map((id)=>({id:id}))
    const mapSelectedActions = selectedActions.map((id)=>({id:id}))
    trackPromise(
      ProfileMaintenanceService.saveProfile(selectedRecords[0], profileName, lastModifier, status, createdBy, mapSelectedModules, mapSelectedActions)
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.success === "Success"){
          store.addNotification({
            ...notification,
            message: "Success! Profile has been saved."
          })
        }
      }))
  }
```

With this, I can call `usePromiseTracker` anywhere on the app to check the promise (axios request)

As seen below:

index.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
import './index.css';
import { usePromiseTracker } from "react-promise-tracker";
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay';

const LoadingIndicator = props => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
    const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker();
    return (
        promiseInProgress && 
            <LoadingOverlay
                active={isActive}
                spinner
                text='Loading your content...'
            >
            <p>Some content or children or something.</p>
             </LoadingOverlay>
    );  
}

render(
    <div>
      <LoadingIndicator/>
      <App />
    </div>,
document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

My current dilemma are:
1. How can I set `isActive` state to true when the promise is in progress?
2. How can I show `<App/>` normally whenever there is no API call? And trigger the overlay when there is one.

TIA

--EDIT--

Answer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthenticatedRoute from './components/AuthenticatedRoute';
import LoginComponent from './components/LoginComponent';
import LogoutComponent from './components/LogoutComponent';
import AuthenticatedPage from './components/pages/AuthenticatedPage';
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component'
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'
import { usePromiseTracker } from "react-promise-tracker";
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay';

function App() {
  const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker();

  return (
      <LoadingOverlay
        active={promiseInProgress}
        spinner
        text=''
      >
      <div>
      <ReactNotification />
      <Router>
        <Switch> 
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginComponent} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginComponent} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logout" exact component={LogoutComponent} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/dashboard" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          {/* Transfers */}
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/inbox" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/sent" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/acknowledged" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/bcpmode" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          {/* Proof List */}
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/proofweb" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/proofothers" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/misc" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          {/* RPS */}
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/clientmaintenance" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/processsftp" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/processpesonet" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/overrideenrollment" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/messageconverter" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />

          {/* Administrator */}
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/usermaintenance" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
          <AuthenticatedRoute path="/profilemaintenance" exact component={AuthenticatedPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
    </LoadingOverlay>

  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're closer than you think you are.

1. In this case, you should delete the `isActive` state rather than syncing it to `promiseInProgress`. Duplicating state is the quickest way to make your components much more complex and less traceable than they could be. In general, you want to store the absolute minimum possible amount of state.
2. Looking at the [docs for react-loading-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay), it looks like it's meant to wrap the component you want to be covered with the overlay. And the `active` prop is used to toggle its visibility.

Taken together, you should end up with something like this:

```
function App() {
  const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker();
  return (
    <LoadingIndicator active={promiseInProgress}>
      {/* other content... */}
    </LoadingIndicator>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally, solved it by using only one state which is `{promiseInProgress}` and applied it onto the active attrib. Also, transferred the overlay on App.js. Will edit for the answer. Thanks!